# how to create environmental variables for my program

Tags: java, environment-variables

I made a program in Java that uses two external databases. The paths to these databases are hard-coded inside my program code.

In order to make this program usable for other users on other computers (who should also install these two databases on their computers), I think that the path for these two databases should be added as environmental variables ? How could this be done ?

I am not a professional when it comes to environmental variables, so can you please advise what should be done in this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: DEpends on which OS system you are using? Mac or Windows? or linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of an environment variable in Java, you write something like this:

```
String pathToDatabase = System.getenv().get("PATH_TO_DATABASE");
```

(where `PATH_TO_DATABASE` is the name of the environment variable). This uses [`System.getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28%29) to get a map of all environment variables.

To *set* the value of an environment variable in Linux, your users can write something like this:

```
export PATH_TO_DATABASE=/this/is/the/path/to/the/database
```

before running the program.

Answer (score 0):

Environment vars are usually not be the best way to handle app config, but if you must, the specific OS docs are needed to learn how to set them and from Java use:

Map map = System.getenv();

Answer (score 0):

Rather than environment variables, a properties file would be useful and more portable. For example, in your properties file you could have the following:

```
db.url = jdbc://foo/bar?whatever
db.user = username
db.password = password
```

Then your code could read that in using the follow:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
  properties.load(new FileInputStream("path/filename"));
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println( "Eeeek!" );
}

System.out.println( properties.getProperty( "db.url" ) );
```

Handily, properties objects allow you to specify defaults, so you could still have the hardcoded values if you want and then override them with the external file.